# What does Manfred's character tell us about human consciousness?

Tags: character-analysis, lord-byron, manfred

I'm currently reading Manfred by Lord Byron and my professor said something that I found interesting. In Act 1, Manfred introduces the idea of humans being 1/2 dust and 1/2 deity. Both link to the problematic consciousness of human beings.

Despite that we can create designs, technology, and other great things, we find ourselves unable to excerpt any sort of control over time due to our own mortality.

Thus, we are deities because of our minds, but we are dust because of our bodies.

I'm interested in how people interpret Manfred's character (and ultimately, Byron's ideology based off of this book) and what Manfred's character shows in human nature (if it shows anything at all).

So...

1. Do qualities of Manfred, the Byronic Hero, reflect how rioters and protesters behave today?
2. If so... is Manfred an "ideal" human being because he defiant against Power?
3. Is the book trying to establish a project in the real world to convince society to not succumb to Power?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Literature.SE. Would you mind [edit]ing this so that it seems less like a discussion thread than a question? This isn't a typical forum; see our [tour]. Also see [ask]. Thanks!